# while using Windrbd, one computer suddenly shutdown. error 5

Tags: drbd

I help you....

While using WinDRBD to connect two computers, one computer suddenly shutdown.

The shutdown side was secondary   ( For convenience, let's call the shutdown Node2 )

```
I entered "drbdadm up foo" in Node2, but the following error message appeared.
DeviceIoControl() failed, error is 5
foo: error sending config command
Command 'drbdsetup new-resource foo 2' terminated with exit code 20
```

Is there any way to recover it?

I need your help

Comment: What version of Windows specifically?

Comment: wersion is window server 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi are you running as Administrator? You have to for drbdadm commands that modify the configuration. Error 5 looks like Permission denied error to me.